# How to send inline SVG in email through PHPMailer

Tags: php, svg, phpmailer

I want to send emails to my users with data through `PHPMailer` and it contains images and `SVG` vectors. For images, it's simple using the `AddAttachment()` method, but I can't send inline `SVG`s. It is possible to send `SVG` in the message body and how.

Comment: Embed them directly into the HTML code, like you would with inline SVG on a normal website …?

Comment: You *can* probably embed it - SVG is just XML anyway - but email clients tend to the archaic so whether anyone will actually see it is a different matter.

Comment: I tried but Gmail doesn't support that. The message body contains the SVG but when I received the email SVG field is empty

Comment: most email clients don't support SVG.

Comment: CD001, I try to send it as an image that everyone can see that no matter what email provider is.

Comment: Robert Longson Yes, that's why I asked here. Is there any way to show SVG all of them?

Comment: *"I try to send it as an image that everyone can see that no matter what email provider is"* - in which case, don't use SVG; rasterise it to a JPG/GIF.

Comment: the problem is that I haven't an SVG image, I have inline SVG code. And I don't know how to rasterize it to a JPG

Comment: Not sure I understand the question correctly. if you want the image to appear in the body of of the email message. for that you would have to use `$mail->isHTML(true);` then `$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';`

Comment: glend thanks, but I have inline SVG in the message body and want to send it like an image.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. SVG couldn't be seen on GMAIL but I could see it on other mail client. I think the solution is to use images (convert the svg files to jpg/png)